# Como enviar un JSON y una imagen en un mismo FETCH?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, fetch

Buenas estoy desarrollando un formulario que tiene  varios input text y un input file. Los envio por separado y cada uno llega bien, es decir recibo la imagen si la envio sola y recibo los inputs si los envio solo, ahora no se como enviarlo todo junto.

(los input fueron guardados en un estado de REACT)
el input file fue enviado dentro de un formData

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Envía todos los datos con `FormData`, tanto textos como imagen. Si no sabes cómo, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar tus códigos, tanto del formulario como la forma de recibirlos en el servidor.

Comment: Ya tienes un formData puedes poner la imagen con un append al formData y enviar el formData con todo, del lado Back podrías usar Formidable para separar datos de archivos...

Comment: Chicos le podria jurar que llevaba 6 horas haciendo eso y nada. Y ahora sí se envia, MUCHAS GRACIAS ;D